# what are the benefits of using base Interface in c#

Tags: c#, interface, repository-pattern

I m working with an application in which Base inteface has been created as below

```
public interface IBaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    bool IsUnitOfWork { get; set; }

    void SaveChanges();
}
```

Then other interfaces extend this interface as

```
public interface ICourseRepository : IBaseRepository
{
    Course GetCourseById(int id);

    List<Course> GetCourses();

    CourseModule GetCourseModuleById(int id);

}
```

Just wondering what would be the advantage of this approach

Comment: The question is not clear - you extend an interface because you want the latter to demand the target class to implement contracts from both. It's by definition. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: This allows any of the comforming Repositories to be *assignable to* "IRepository". Each Repository having it's own "I_x_Repository" interface is secondary to the "IRepository" unification/contract.

Comment: The advantage is that other repository interfaces (such as `ICourseRepository`) can enforce the functional contract of `IBaseRepository` without having to duplicate it multiple times.  So now anything that implements `ICourseRepository` must also implement `IBaseRepository`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base repository allows you to specify behavior you want all repository contracts to have without repeating it in every `IMyEntityRepository` you create.

Even more fun though is then implementing a Base Repository like this and specifying generic code for generic operations:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {

    private DbContext _context;

    public Repository(DbContext context) {
        if (context == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        _context = context;
    }
    protected DbContext DbContext { get { return _context; } }

    public void Create(TEntity entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id) {
        return DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

etc., Then have your MyEntityReporitory extend your BaseRepository

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse the base interface for multiple classes/interfaces without requiring implementation of other interfaces also - so you can have `IsUnitOfWork` available on a bunch of classes, without needing to also implement `GetCourseById` on all of those classes.  However you can also ensure that all CourseRepositories are treated as units of work.